# Bake bone movement

Tags: export, bones, constraints, baking

I have added bone constraint to make bone a child of a moving empty. For exporting purposes I need to bake the bone's movement into an action of the bone's armature (so I can delete the empty and still have the bone move in the way it used to). I have tried Pose > Animation > Bake Action but it just creates a keyframe at the beginning and at the end of an animation and the bone doesn't even move at all.

Comment: Exporting as FBX does that for you. I'm not sure what you mean by deleting the empty object, but if you make the animation a fake user you can export the animation alone without any objects in the scene.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! May I ask what to do if I have created multiple actions for the empty and I have multiple actions for the armature too but each empty's action is supposed to be mixed with exactly one specific action of the armature when exporting. How do I avoid creating a mess of actions that weren't supposed to be merged together?

Comment: Each Action has  a unique name. I don't know what program you are exporting to, but e.g. in Unity you can call the actions by name.